# Keyerror when searching for a date PRIOR to Date TIme in python pandas dataframe using getloc ffill

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following data frame. I want to get the nearest date using get_loc ffill parameter as mentioned in the code snippet. 
DataFrame:

```
Date Time,Close,High,Low,Open,Volume
2020-01-02 22:45:00,326.75,329.3,326.5,329.3,0.0
2020-01-02 22:50:00,328.0606,330.0708,325.6666,326.7106,9178.0
2020-01-02 22:55:00,327.4,328.3,327.4,328.05,1035.0
...
2020-02-07 04:50:00,372.05,375.0,372.0,373.0,4936.0
2020-02-07 04:55:00,372.1156,373.3588,370.3559,372.3656,7548.0
```

Code Snippet

```
df_colname = 'Date Time'
pandas_datetime_colname = 'Pandas Date Time'
df[pandas_datetime_colname] = pd.to_datetime(df[df_colname])
df.set_index(pandas_datetime_colname, inplace=True)
dt = pd.to_datetime(inputdatetime)
idx = df.index.get_loc(dt, 'ffill')
print("Date Time: " + str(inputdatetime) + " :idx " + str(idx))
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

This returns the correct date 2020-01-02 22:45:00 when I provide date as 2020-02-02 22:50:00 but when I give a date PRIOR to the first date, I get a keyerror
*KeyError: Timestamp('2019-12-20 22:45:00')*
 I also don't get an error when I give a date AFTER the last date in the dataframe

I looked through the documents but could not find why I get an error only for dates PRIOR . I was hoping to get some kind of a None object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_loc.html):

`ffill: find the PREVIOUS index value if no exact match.`

Giving a datetime with no prior datetimes in the index, will result in an error due to it giving the closest match in the `PREVIOUS` index value. Since there is no such index value, it throws an error.

I believe what you're looking for is the `nearest` argument, instead of `ffill`:

`nearest: use the NEAREST index value if no exact match. Tied distances are broken by preferring the larger index value.`